# Draw a quarter circle at the end of a straight line

Tags: python, geometry, point, shapely

I have coordinates of some points. My task is to get the direction of those points and find where future possible points will be located in the calculated direction. To do so, I have planned the following-

1. Fit a line to the points
2. Draw a quarter circle at the end of the fitted line. In common sense, the quarter circle might not be the right option to go for. However, it is a part of another problem and has to be solved this way.

I am using the following codes to fit a line

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

x = [1,2,3,2,5,6,7,8,9,10] 
y = [2,4,11,8,8,18,14,11,18,20]
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
line = [slope*i+intercept for i in x]
plt.plot(x, line)
```

Suppose, the two points on the fitted line is (9,17) and (10,19). How can I draw a quarter circle at (10,19) with a radius of 5 in the direction of the line?

[image]

Ultimately, I will have a point location and I have to check whether the point falls inside the quarter circle or not, I assume which could be done with shapely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether point **P** falls inside the quarter circle, you can find distance from line end **B** (length of **BP**) and cosine of angle between unit  line direction vector **d** and vector **BP**

```
distance = sqrt(BP.x * BP.x + BP.y * BP.y)

cosine = (d.x * BP.x + d.y * BP.y) / (distance)

if (distance < radius) and (cosine >= sqrt(2)/2) 
  P in sector
```

Unit vector **d** might be calculated from data you already have:

```
d.x = sign(slope) * sqrt(1/(1+slope**2))
d.y = sqrt(slope**2/1+slope**2)
```

Note that sign of components is not defined clearly (because two opposite vectors have the same slope)

---

To address the main question - end points of arc might be calculated using rotated (by Pi/4) direction vector

```
cf = sqrt(2)/2
arcbegin.x = b.x + radius * d.x * cf - radius * d.y * cf
arcbegin.y = b.y + radius * d.x * cf + radius * d.y * cf
arcend.x = b.x + radius * d.x * cf + radius * d.y * cf
arcend.y = b.y - radius * d.x * cf + radius * d.y * cf
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calculating all the math by yourself, you can delegate it to Shapely.

First, create a circle at the end of the line with the help of [`buffer`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.buffer):

```
from shapely.affinity import rotate
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point
from shapely.ops import split

a = (10, 20)
b = (15, 30)
ab = LineString([a, b])  # the line you got from linear regression
circle = Point(b).buffer(5)
```

[image]

Now, let's get two new lines that will delimit the area of the sector we want. We will do it by rotating the line using [`rotate`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.affinity.rotate) to 135º at each direction, so that the sector's central angle will be 360º - 135º * 2 = 90º, which is a quarter of circle:

```
left_border = rotate(ab, -135, origin=b)
right_border = rotate(ab, 135, origin=b)
```

[image]

Finally, use [`split`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.ops.split) to get the sector:

```
splitter = LineString([*left_border.coords, *right_border.coords[::-1]])
sector = split(circle, splitter)[1]
```

[image]

From here you can easily find out if a point lies inside of the sector using [`contains`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.contains) method. For example:

```
points_of_interest = [Point(16, 32), Point(12, 30)]
for point in points_of_interest:
    print(sector.contains(point))
# True
# False
```

[image]

Comment: The method you have shown here actually is helping me avoid all extra mathematical equation I am writing myself. Your answer is phenomenal. I was wondering how you are plotting the shapely object as a figure. I can only do that for polygon by taking their exterior points.

Comment: Glad it helped. Both [JupyterLab and Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/) produce these images automatically as cells output. To draw complex figures I put them together in a not-documented `GeometryCollection` class like: `from shapely.geometry import GeometryCollection; GeometryCollection([some_line, some_polygon, etc...])` and it simply gives these nice figures.

Answer (score 1):

I think You should implement the arch as follows. (I just shown the your missing logic, You haft to add your plot ). Good luck

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

x = [1,2,3,2,5,6,7,8,9,10] 
y = [2,4,11,8,8,18,14,11,18,20]
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
line = [slope*i + intercept for i in x]


# Logic Part *****************************************************

from matplotlib.patches import Arc
import math


# circuile parameters
R = 5
xEnd,yEnd = 10 , 20 #Your end point cords, in your case Point B

LowerThita = math.degrees(math.atan(slope)) - 45
UpperThita = math.degrees(math.atan(slope)) + 45

# Figure setup
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(-R , (R+xEnd) * 1.05)
ax.set_ylim(-R , (R+yEnd) * 1.05)


# Arcs
ax.add_patch(Arc((xEnd, yEnd), R, R,
                 theta1=LowerThita, theta2=UpperThita, edgecolor='k'))

plt.show()

#NOTE : You Haft to add your line to the plot
```